# Reference to a vector still prints as a vector?

Tags: pointers, rust

Silly n00b trying to learn a bit about Rust. Here is my program:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    println!("{:?}", v);
    println!("{:?}", &v);
}
```

Produced the output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

What is the point of the `&`? I was half expecting it to print a memory address.

I was originally thrown by this in the [intro](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20vec%20%3D%20vec!%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20for%20x%20in%20%26vec%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20x)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%7D) where it looks like they are looping *through* a reference. My guess is that Rust does some magic and detects it is a memory address of a vector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the point of the &?

The `&` takes the reference of an object, as you surmised. However, there's a [`Debug` implementation for references to `Debug` types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b7fb57529aded92c4f470568e6b5ea7a5a28f6a4/src/libcore/fmt/mod.rs#L783-L796) that just prints out the referred-to object. This is done because Rust tends to prefer value equality over reference equality:

```rust
impl<'a, T: ?Sized + $tr> $tr for &'a T {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> Result { $tr::fmt(&**self, f) }
}
```

If you'd like to print the memory address, you can use `{:p}`:

```
let v = vec![1,2,3];
println!("{:p}", &v);
```

> it looks like they are looping through a reference

The `for i in foo` syntax sugar calls `into_iterator` on `foo`, and there's an [implementation of `IntoIterator` for `&Vec`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b7fb57529aded92c4f470568e6b5ea7a5a28f6a4/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L1520-L1528) that returns an iterator of references to items in the iterator:

```rust
fn into_iter(self) -> slice::Iter<'a, T> {
    self.iter()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I read the section on iterators and saw that the `for i in &v` is giving me i as a reference to each element of v. The for loop is doing the magic of figuring out I want references to each element of the iterable – as opposed to trying to iterate through a pointer. Is that correct?

Comment: @speg I added a part about that. Basically, `for i in foo` uses `IntoIterator`, and there's an implementation of that trait for `&Vec<T>` that delegates to `Vec::iter`. `Vec::iter` returns an iterator that yields references to each item in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

The magic is AFAIK in the formatter rather than the compiler. See for example:

```
fn take_val<T>(a:Vec<T> ) {}
fn take_ref<T>(b:&Vec<T>) {}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    take_val(&v);
    take_ref(&v);

}
```

Fails with following error:

```
<anon>:6:14: 6:16 error: mismatched types:
 expected `collections::vec::Vec<_>`,
    found `&collections::vec::Vec<_>`
(expected struct `collections::vec::Vec`,
    found &-ptr) [E0308]
<anon>:6     take_val(&v);
```

Which suggests this is due to formatter not wanting to show difference between a reference and a value. In older versions of Rust a `&v` would have been shown as `&[1, 2, 3]`, if my memory serves me correct.

`&` has special meaning in Rust. It's not just a reference, it's a note that the value is borrowed to one or more functions/methods.